GitHub + Google Colab
Не могу сделать push в гитхаб из колаба.
Вот что делаю:
!git config --global user.email "моя_почта@gmail.com"
!git clone https://github.com/мой_аккаунт/мой_репозиторий.git
# вношу изменения
!git add .
!git commit -m 'Внёс какие-то изменения'
!git push origin main

Появляется ошибка:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Я создал пару ssh ключей, содержимое pub добавил в ключи в аккаунте гитхаба, пробую в колабе
!eval $(ssh-agent -s)
!ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Снова ошибка:
Agent pid 15997
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Я выяснил, что это из-а того, что SSH Agent не запущен. Но он ведь запустился как 15997, а вот с ключом проблемы.
В чём может быть проблема?

Вместо запуска агента прописывайте ключи в конфиге ssh.

Спасибо, помогло! Пришлось создать этот config, потом ещё known_hosts, автоматически ключи не добавлялись в этот файл, нашёл в интернете строки для гитхаба. Клонировал репозиторий, внёс изменения и успешно запушил)) спасибо ещё раз

@Irking Оформите сами ответ на свой вопрос с понятным описанием, что вы делали. Я думаю, кому-то ещё может пригодится.

По совету @user7860670 и @CrazyElf
Надо связать google colab и github. Я сделал с помощью SSH ключей.
Сгенерировал ключи:
!ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "any_keys"


По умолчанию, ключи будут сохранены в директорию root/.ssh. Нажмите Enter, чтобы принять стандартную директорию, или введите новое местоположение, если требуется (указанный каталог должен существовать).
Затем будет предложено ввести кодовую фразу (passphrase) и повторить, а можно оставить пустой её, нажать Enter и продолжить настройку.
Открываем настройки (Settings) аккаунта Github -> вкладка SSH and GPG keys -> кнопка New SSH key.

В первое поле вводим любое имя для ключа, второе оставляем без изменений, а в третье вставьте содержимое файла id_rsa.pub. Сохраните ключ (Add SSH key).
Затем в root/.ssh надо создать файлы config и known_hosts
!touch config
!touch known_hosts

Открываем config в любом текстовом редакторе и добавляем туда следующее:
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Это конфигурация для подключения к GitHub через SSH.
Открываем known_hosts в любом текстовом редакторе и добавляем туда следующее:
github.com ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIOMqqnkVzrm0SdG6UOoqKLsabgH5C9okWi0dh2l9GKJl
github.com ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBEmKSENjQEezOmxkZMy7opKgwFB9nkt5YRrYMjNuG5N87uRgg6CLrbo5wAdT/y6v0mKV0U2w0WZ2YB/++Tpockg=
github.com ssh-rsa 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

Эти строки представляют собой публичные ключи для серверов GitHub, используемые для аутентификации пользователей при подключении через SSH.
Теперь при подключении к GitHub Ваш SSH-клиент будет знать эти ключи и сможет безопасно устанавливать соединение.
Готово.
Говорят, что команда ssh github.com автоматически добавляет информацию в config, а ещё есть аналогичная команда для формирования known_hosts. Но у меня эти команды не прошли. Вероятно, проблема в специфике колаба, а может я что-то не так сделал.
